# Lippia Mobile - Error en docker al correr comando docker-compose up

Tags: docker, programación-móvil, framework

he estado intentando correr el ejemplo de lippia de mobile, usando docker, pero a la hora de ejecutar el docker-compose up, me encuentro con un error en el conainer samsung_s7_9.0.

Me encuentro utilizando una distro de linux llamada Kubuntu

Dejo el error que obtengo:

```
dante@Dante-Kubuntu:~/Escritorio/Crowdar/Lippia/MOBILE/Lippia-mobile-sample-project$ sudo docker-compose up
WARNING: The apkDirectory variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Creating network "lippia-mobile-sample-project_default" with the default driver
Creating lippia-mobile-sample-project_selenium_hub-mobile-apk_1 ... done
Creating lippia-mobile-sample-project_nginx_web-sample_1        ... done
Creating lippia-mobile-sample-project_jenkins-mobile_apk_1      ... done
Creating lippia-mobile-sample-project_samsung_s7_9.0_1          ... error

ERROR: for lippia-mobile-sample-project_samsung_s7_9.0_1  Cannot create container for service samsung_s7_9.0: create .: volume name is too short, names should be at least two alphanumeric characters

ERROR: for samsung_s7_9.0  Cannot create container for service samsung_s7_9.0: create .: volume name is too short, names should be at least two alphanumeric characters
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Según puedo entender, hay un problema con el nombre del volumen creado en este container, pero cuando reviso el docker-compose, la ruta del volumen parece estar correcta. Dejo el contenido del docker-compose:

```
# Note: It requires docker-compose 1.13.0
#
# Usage: docker-compose up -d
version: "2.2"

services:
  jenkins-mobile_apk:
    image: crowdar/jenkinsbo:demoweb
    privileged: true
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 50000:50000
    # Change path of apk that you want to test. I use sample_apk that I provide in folder "example"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home

  # Selenium hub
  selenium_hub-mobile-apk:
    image: selenium/hub:3.14.0-curium
    ports:
      - 4444:4444

  # Docker-Android for Android application testing
  #nexus_7.1.1:
  # image: budtmo/docker-android-x86-7.1.1
  #  privileged: true
    # Increase scale number if needed
    #  scale: 1
    # depends_on:
    # - selenium_hub
    #ports:
    #  - 6081:6080
    # Change path of apk that you want to test. I use sample_apk that I provide in folder "example"
    #volumes:
    #  - ${apkDirectory}:/root/tmp/sample_apk
    #  - ./video-nexus_7.1.1:/tmp/video
    #environment:
    #  - DEVICE=Nexus 5
    #  - CONNECT_TO_GRID=true
    #  - APPIUM=true
    #  - SELENIUM_HOST=selenium_hub
    #  - AUTO_RECORD=true


 # Docker-Android for Android application testing
  samsung_s7_9.0:
    image: budtmo/docker-android-x86-9.0
    privileged: true
    # Increase scale number if needed
    scale: 1
    depends_on:
      - selenium_hub-mobile-apk
    ports:
      - 6080:6080
    # Change path of apk that you want to test. I use sample_apk that I provide in folder "example"
    volumes:
      - ${apkDirectory}:/root/tmp/sample_apk
      - ./video-samsung_s7_9:/tmp/video
    environment:
      - DEVICE=Samsung Galaxy S7
      - CONNECT_TO_GRID=true
      - APPIUM=true
      - SELENIUM_HOST=selenium_hub-mobile-apk
      - AUTO_RECORD=true

  nginx_web-sample:
    image: nginx:stable
    volumes:
      - ./docker/jenkins_home/reportsVolume:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    environment:
      - TZ=America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires
```

Espero puedan ayudarme a solucionar esto, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder utilizar ese docker-compose debes enviarle el argumento `${apkDirectory}`.
La idea de este argumento es probar la aplicación que tengas. Para poder probar la que viene en ese proyecto de ejemplo podes usar el siguiente comando:

`apkDirectory=./sample_apk docker-compose up`

Para enviar argumentos se escriben antes del comando (`apkDirectory=sample_apk`) este valor es el nombre del directorio que esta en el proyecto de ejemplo que contiene los archivos .apk.

En el caso de probar otra apk podes usar el directorio de tu pc local que la contenga y hacer referencia al nombre de la apk en el **pom** del proyecto.

Por ejemplo si tu aplicación esta en la dirección: `/opt/apk/app.apk` usas el comando:

`apkDirectory=/opt/apk docker-compose up`

En el **pom** del proyecto cambias la dirección de la aplicación a:

`<crowdar.appLocation>/root/tmp/sample_apk/app.apk</crowdar.appLocation>`

esto se debe a que el volume esta apuntado en tu directorio local con el directorio `/root/tmp/sample_apk del container`.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas exportarlas antes de ejecutar Docker-compose

```
export apkDirectory="xxxxx"
docker-compose up
```

Aquí [una respuesta en la que lo tratan en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43544328/pass-argument-to-docker-compose)

Aquí la [documentación de docker al respecto](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution)

Answer (score -1):

Me sucedía lo mismo. Comparto salida de consola:

```
zxxxa@underc0de:~/eclipse-workspace/Lippia-mobile-sample-project$ sudo docker-compose up
```

WARNING: The apkDirectory variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
lippia-mobile-sample-project_selenium_hub-mobile-apk_1 is up-to-date
lippia-mobile-sample-project_nginx_web-sample_1 is up-to-date
lippia-mobile-sample-project_jenkins-mobile_apk_1 is up-to-date
Creating lippia-mobile-sample-project_samsung_s7_9.0_1 ... error

ERROR: for lippia-mobile-sample-project_samsung_s7_9.0_1  Cannot create container for service samsung_s7_9.0: create .: volume name is too short, names should be at least two alphanumeric characters

ERROR: for samsung_s7_9.0  Cannot create container for service samsung_s7_9.0: create .: volume name is too short, names should be at least two alphanumeric characters
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

En la documentación del Framework recomiendan lanzar stack con:

```
sudo apkDirectory=./sample_apk docker-compose up
```